# How to define number sequence in string?

Tags: java

I have a task to create a string with a non-defined length (input digits from the keyboard until the user presses "Enter"), then I have to define how many of digits are in sequence. Unfortunately I can't handle this. I think I'm almost there but I'm not. I've created the string which I hoped to copy character by character to an array and then compare each digit with the next one, but I have trouble with copying characters into an array.

Here's my code:

```
int sum = 0;
String someSymbols = sc.nextLine();
int array [] = new int[someSymbols.length()];
for(int i=0; i<someSymbols.length(); i++){
    for (int j=0; j<=array.length; j++){
        array[j] = someSymbols.charAt(i);
    }
    sum++;
}
```

Comment: but you already have it on someSymbols.length()

Comment: @Victor: "in sequence" presumably means "1239" would yield 3, not 4.

Comment: Your English is better than you think, no need to apologize (or if you do, put it at the end so it's not in the way of your question). The button you used for adding code is for adding *runnable* in-browser JavaScript, HTML, and/or CSS, not Java, so next time use the `{}` button (or just indent four spaces).

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve]  without the need of a `Scanner`. What is your inputs used here ?

Comment: Yes, but I have to operate with digits, to compare them. That's easy in array, but I have to input symbols untill press Enter. The Arrays has to have lenght with declaration. How to read an array with no specified length?

Comment: @theMadMax: It's just as easy to use `charAt(index)` for this task, no need for an array. But if you want an array, good news: There's a method for that: [`String#toCharArray`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray--). It literally does exactly that: Gives you a `char[]` for the characters in the string. Always worth looking closely at the documentation.

Comment: you want to count only digit from user input?

Comment: @SasikumarMurugesan: *"in sequence"*

Comment: you mean if input is 1234a8 means then result should be 1234. am I right?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you provide an example of the expected result for let's say this user input `1g3h6j3lk4kj56`

Comment: I think that in your INNER for loop you need to change j <= array.length to j < array.length, because in last loop you're gonna get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to assign something to array[j].

Comment: Testing for a number can be done with c >= '0' && c <= '9'. No need for an array.

Comment: Use a **List**!!

Comment: Thanks for advices and recommendations guys!
Przemysław Moskal: You're right! There was a problem with second loop, because of the reason you said!
Now I start to read about lists, and when Im done, I'll write :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: T.J. Crowder, I tried to use this "String#toCharArray" but it didn't work out. It seems there's no function like that at my Eclipse :( or probably I couldn't find the way...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of what you want to achieve but here are 2 examples for inspiration:

**Taking digits until reaching a different digit. Ignoring non digits**

```
String s = "22u223r5";

String digitsOnly = s.replaceAll("[^\\d.]", "");

int firstDifferentDigit = -1;
for(int i = 1; i < digitsOnly.length(); i++) {
  if(digitsOnly.charAt(i) != digitsOnly.charAt(i-1)) {
    firstDifferentDigit = i;
    break;
  }
}

System.out.println("firstDifferentDigit:"+firstDifferentDigit);
System.out.println(digitsOnly.substring(0,firstDifferentDigit));
```

Outputs

```
firstDifferentDigit:4
2222
```

**Taking digits until first non digit**

```
String s = "124g35h6j3lk4kj56";

int firstNonDigitCharacter = -1;
for(int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
  if(s.charAt(i) < '0' || s.charAt(i) > '9') {
    firstNonDigitCharacter = i;
    break;
  }
}

System.out.println("firstNonDigitCharacter:"+firstNonDigitCharacter);
System.out.println(s.substring(0,firstNonDigitCharacter));
```

Outputs

```
firstNonDigitCharacter:3
124
```

**EDIT**
This works for how you described the exercise:

```
String someSymbols = "72745123";
List<String> sequences = new ArrayList<>();

boolean inSequence = false; // will flag if we are currently within a sequence
StringBuilder currentSequence = new StringBuilder(); // this will store the numbers of the sequence

for(int i = 0; i < someSymbols.length(); i++) {
  char currentChar = someSymbols.charAt(i);
  char nextChar = 0;
  if(i < someSymbols.length()-1)
    nextChar = someSymbols.charAt(i+1);

  // if next number is 1 more than the current one, we are in a sequence
  if(currentChar == nextChar-1) {
    inSequence = true;
    currentSequence.append(String.valueOf(currentChar));

  // if next number is NOT 1 more than the current one and we are in a sequence, it is the last of the sequence
  } else if(inSequence) {
    currentSequence.append(String.valueOf(currentChar));
    sequences.add(currentSequence.toString());
    currentSequence = new StringBuilder();
    inSequence = false;
  }
}

System.out.println(sequences);
```

Outputs

```
[45, 123]
```

Comment: If I correctly understood the task: We have a series of numbers: 7, 2, 7, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3. In this case there are two groups of numbers which are in sequence ...4, 5... and ...1, 2, 3... therefore we have 5 numbers in all string which are in sequence! Am I right?

Comment: well, I guess you should understand the question better than us:D

Comment: I added a solution for this specific example.  Should work fine

Answer (score 0):

I deleted my first answer, because I got the question wrong, thought it's about a character sequence, of which some happen to be digits.

Trying to wrap my head around the new functional style in Java8, but conversion is complicated and full of pitfalls. Surely, this isn't canonical. I guess a collector could be appropriate here, but I broke out and made half of the work in an recursive method.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

String s = "123534567321468"
List<Integer> li = IntStream.range (0, s.length()-2).filter (i -> (s.charAt(i+1) != s.charAt(i)+1)).collect (ArrayList::new, List::add, List::addAll);

li.add (s.length()-1);
int maxDiff (int last, List<Integer> li , int maxdiff) {
    if (li.isEmpty ()) 
        return maxdiff;
    return maxDiff (li.get(0), li.subList (1, li.size () - 1), Math.max (li.get(0) - last, maxdiff));
}
int result = maxDiff (0, li, 0);
```

It starts elegantly.

```
IntStream.range (0, s.length()-2).filter (i -> (s.charAt(i+1) != s.charAt(i)+1))
|  Expression value is: java.util.stream.IntPipeline$9@5ce81285
|    assigned to temporary variable $20 of type IntStream

-> $20.forEach (i -> System.out.println (i));
2
3
8
9
10
11
12
```

That's the List of indexes, where chains of numbers are broken.

```
 String s = "123534567321468"
```

123 is from 0 to 2, 5 is just 3, 34567, the later winner from 4 to 8, ...

Note that we needn't transform the String into Numbers, since the characters are chained in ASCII or UTF-X one by one, like numbers.

To convert it into a List, the complicated collect method is used, because Array of primitive int doesn't work well with List .

For the last interval, li.add (s.length()-1) has to be added - adding elements wouldn't work with array.

maxDiff protocolls the max so far, the last element and repeatedly takes the head from the list, to compare it with the last element to build the current difference.

The Code was testet in the jshell of Java9, which is an amazing tool and needs no embedding class, nor 'main' for snippets. :)

Just for comparison, this is my solution in scala:

```
val s = "123534567321468"
val cuts = (0 to s.length-2).filter (i => {s.charAt(i+1) != s.charAt(i)+1}).toList ::: s.length-1 :: Nil
(0 :: cuts).sliding (2, 1).map {p => p(1) - p(0)}.max
```

Sliding(a,b) defines a window of width a=2 which moves forward by b=1.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot! I made it with your help! It turns out that the task was to count how many numbers occur in the string of any symbols. As simple as that. My bad! But I'm grateful to be part of this forum :)

Here's the code:

```
    String f = sc.nextLine();
    int count = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<f.length(); i++){
        if((f.charAt(i)>='0') && (f.charAt(i)<='9')){
        count++;
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The numbers in the row are : " + count);
```

Comment: if you use lambdas, you could make it a oneliner